# Where can I find Open Data on Nigeria's Annual Budget?

Tags: data-request, africa

I need a resource or information on where/how I can get access to Nigeria's Annual Budget

Answer (score 1):

Nigeria has a federal level open data site: http://data.edostate.gov.ng/

The link below is to the category on Finance. Of the datasets listed, one is labeled 2015 Budget.

http://data.edostate.gov.ng/group/finance